# Send Ipc from Vue js to Electron

Tags: javascript, vue.js, electron

what I want to do: so that an event in the backend electron process is triggered on a button click, for example
`ipcRenderer.sendSync('synchronous-message', 'ping'`
, but I am getting an error like this in my render process:
`Uncaught TypeError: r.existsSync is not a function`.
The moment I write in App.vue: `<script> import { ipcRenderer } from "electron" </script>`
my settings:

```
//vue.config.js:
module.exports  = {
    publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV  ===  'production'  ?  './'  :  '/',
    pluginOptions: {
        electronBuilder: {
          preload: 'src/preload.js',
          nodeIntegration: true,
        }
      }
}
//main.js:
function createWindow() {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      enableRemoteModule: true,
      nodeIntegrationInWorker: true,
      preload: path.join(__dirname, '/src/preload.js')
    }
  })
```

code ipcMain:

```
const { ipcMain } = require('electron')
ipcMain.on('asynchronous-message', (event, arg) => {
  console.log(arg) // prints "ping"
  event.reply('asynchronous-reply', 'pong')
})

ipcMain.on('synchronous-message', (event, arg) => {
  console.log(arg) // prints "ping"
  event.returnValue = 'pong'
})
```

code ipcrenderer:

```
console.log(ipcRenderer.sendSync('synchronous-message', 'ping')) // prints "pong"
ipcRenderer.on('asynchronous-reply', (event, arg) => {
console.log(arg) // prints "pong"
```

Comment: Please add you ipcRenderer and ipcMain code as well so that people can better understand what could be the problem.

Comment: I added, you can check

Comment: You imported ipcrenderer above where you use it right?